# mutate values in a column using ifelse best practices

Tags: r

I just wrote this ugly, nasty code

```
marge_c <- student_feedback %>% 
mutate(lunch = ifelse(lunch == "standard", 1, ifelse(lunch == "free/reduced", 2, 0)))
marge_c <- marge_c %>% mutate(parental_level_of_education = (parental_level_of_education = ifelse(parental_level_of_education == "some college", 1, ifelse(parental_level_of_education == "high school", 2, ifelse(parental_level_of_education == "associate's degree", 3, ifelse(parental_level_of_education == "bachelor's degree",4, ifelse(parental_level_of_education == "master's degree",5,0)))))))
marge_c <- marge_c %>% mutate(gender = ifelse(gender == "female", 1, ifelse(gender == "male",2,0)))
marge_c <- marge_c %>% mutate(test_preparation_course = ifelse(test_preparation_course == "none",1, ifelse(test_preparation_course =="completed", 2,0)))
marge_c <- marge_c %>% mutate(race_ethnicity = ifelse(race_ethnicity == "group A", 1, ifelse(race_ethnicity == "group B", 2, ifelse(race_ethnicity == "group C", 3, ifelse(race_ethnicity == "group D",4, 0)))))
```

There has to be a better way to do this, right? is there a more efficient way or a neater way? or am I stuck doing it this way each time? can I write a loop to loop through the columns or something? I am not familiar for how to bets do this in R

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Rather than nesting your `ifelse` statements you can use `case_when`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when with `dplyr` or just use base R `x$y[x$y==z] <- new_val` . Also you don't multiple `mutate` statements: you can put them all in one. Even with separate statements, no need to keep assigning back to `marge_c` - you can pipe across multiple lines.

Comment: @SamR That `case_when` seems like the best way to go! so much simpler. Also, thanks for pointing out the pip thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the suggestion from @SamR I was able to write this

````
    marge_c <- student_feedback %>% mutate(gender = case_when(
    gender == "female" ~ 0,
    gender == "male" ~ 1
  ), race_ethnicity = case_when(
    race_ethnicity == "group A" ~ 1,
    race_ethnicity == "group B" ~ 2,
    race_ethnicity == "group C" ~ 3,
    race_ethnicity == "group D" ~ 4
  ), parental_level_of_education = case_when(
    parental_level_of_education == "bachelor's degree" ~ 1,
    parental_level_of_education == "some college" ~ 2,
    parental_level_of_education == "master's degree" ~ 3,
    parental_level_of_education == "associate's degree" ~ 4,
    parental_level_of_education == "some high school" ~ 5,
    parental_level_of_education == "high school" ~ 6
  ), lunch = case_when(
    lunch == "standard" ~ 1,
    lunch == "free/reduced" ~ 2
  ), test_preparation_course = case_when(
    test_preparation_course == "none" ~ 0,
    test_preparation_course == "completed" ~ 1
  ))```
````